# When to use TestClass instance variables vs Pytest Fixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, fixtures

When is it appropriate to use a Pytest fixture versus an instance variable?

Suppose I have a large expected JSON output stored locally that several tests employ. Which of the following approaches is more appropriate? I can see that the state of the object remains unchanged from test to test.

```
@pytest.fixture
def expected_output():
    return <fixture>

def test_1(expected_output):
    <do something>
    assert output == expected_output

def test_2(expected_output):
    <do something>
    assert output == expected_output
```

```
class SomeTestClass(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.expected_output = <fixture>

    def test_1(self):
        <do something>
        self.assertEqual(output, self.expected_output)

    def test_2(self):
        <do something>
        self.assertEqual(output, self.expected_output)
```

I've combed through the Pytest docs and don't seem to understand the distinction. Having instance variables seems to carry a lot of benefits of fixtures--i.e., sharing values across tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first difference you have already shown in your example: a fixture does not need a test class.

If you use a test class, you can also use the `setup` method in `pytest`, no need to use `unittest.TestCase`:

```py
class SomeTestClass:
    def setup_method(self):
        self.expected_output = <fixture>

    def test_1(self):
        <do something>
        assert output == self.expected_output
```

This is described as the [classic xunit-style setup](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html) in `pytest`. From that documentation:

> While these setup/teardown methods are simple and familiar to those coming from a unittest or nose background, you may also consider using pytest’s more powerful [fixture mechanism](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture) which leverages the concept of dependency injection, allowing for a more modular and more scalable approach for managing test state, especially for larger projects and for functional testing. You can mix both fixture mechanisms in the same file but test methods of `unittest.TestCase` subclasses cannot receive fixture arguments.

Generally I would advice against mixing `unittest` and `pytest` for new test code. There is nothing in `unittest` that cannot be done with pytest, but you cannot run `unittest` against a test that uses `pytest` features.

In your concrete example, you actually don't want an instance variable, because the expected output does not change with the test. You could just declare the variable statically and use it (both in or outside of classes), or you could use a class variable (and use `setup_class` to set it in `pytest`).

For this trivial example it probably makes no real difference which concept to use, but if you you need a `setup` and a `teardown`, fixtures can be more helpfull, as they provide both:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def some_resource():
    resource = acquire_resource()
    yield resource
    free(resource)
```

In the end, there is no "appropriate" choice in the cases where you can use both variants, but using fixtures always feels more consistent - one mechanism instead of two different ones - and it is the `pytest` way. Not the least factor - most people using `pytest` use fixtures in these cases, so finding help and sharing code is easier if you use the same.